# How to merge/overwrite identical rows without error sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function that checks the table for duplicate rows and overwrites the previous ones.

It has worked for me in the past when moving the id to another row but now this error occurs:

```
raise orm_exc.FlushError(
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <Usage at 0x7fb3f2a035e0> 
with identity key (<class 'blueprints.site.usage.Usage'>, (859,), None) 
conflicts with persistent instance <Usage at 0x7fb3d896ee50>
```

And when I assign a new id to the updated row there's no error. How can I reassign the old id to the new row?

```
def save_as_single_row(self):
    """
    Save usage as a single row in usage table.
    """
    query = Usage.query.filter_by(site_id=self.site_id, invoice_num=self.invoice_num, 
    supply_charge=self.supply_charge)
    this_usage = query.all()
    if not this_usage or (len(this_usage) == 1 and this_usage[0] == self):
        print(self.start_date, 'self')
        self.save()
        print(self.start_date)
        return self

    print('Usage already exists', this_usage[-1].__dict__)
    self.id = this_usage[-1].id
    self.credit = this_usage[-1].credit
    self.awaiting_bill_combine = this_usage[-1].awaiting_bill_combine
    self.awaiting_site_combine = this_usage[-1].awaiting_site_combine
    query.delete()
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()
    return self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer was much simpler than I thought, I removed `db.session.add(self)` and added:

```
    new_obj = db.session.merge(this_usage[-1])
    db.session.commit()
```

It seems like this merges the values of the most recent row with the id of the original row.

For anyone else wondering - [here is some more info.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#merging)

**EDIT:**

`session.merge()` stopped playing nicely for multiple rows so I stopped using `db.session.add(self)` and the changes committed correctly.